# Troubleshooting pybitcointools transaction signing/verification

Tags: ecdsa, python

I'm having several problems getting tests to successfully run [under my fork](https://github.com/wizardofozzie/pybitcointools) (or vbuterin's [pybitcointools](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools), and I'm hoping someone with a combined Python / Bitcoin knowledge can provide some insight.

Here's the error message (as submitted to [#145](https://github.com/vbuterin/pybitcointools/issues/145)):

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_all (__main__.TestTransaction)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/AA78F2EC-3EE8-40F4-A318-8A9AB1BCB5FF/Pythonista3/Documents/pybitcointools-vbuterin/test.py", line 179, in test_all
    self.assertTrue(verify_tx_input(tx1, 0, mscript, sig1, pubs[1]), "Verification Error")
AssertionError: Verification Error

======================================================================
FAIL: test_all (__main__.TestTransactionSignVerify)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/AA78F2EC-3EE8-40F4-A318-8A9AB1BCB5FF/Pythonista3/Documents/pybitcointools-vbuterin/test.py", line 133, in test_all
    "Verification error"
AssertionError: Verification error

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 18 tests in 6.944s

FAILED (failures=2, errors=2)
```

I've got a hunch this has to do with the introduction of `low_s` (ie `s = N-s if s>N//2 else s`) for ECDSA signing, but can't be certain.

Can anyone point out where things are going astray?

Comment: Can you post a diff of your branch vs. vbuterin's?

Comment: @JimmySong git is not one of my strong suits (and currently using iOS for Python) so it's doable, but can you remind how I do a diff of my HEAD vs vbuterin's master?

Comment: `git remote add vbuterin git@github.com:vbuterin/pybitcointools`. Then `git  fetch vbuterin`. Then `git diff vbuterin/master`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I figured it out.

It was an issue with the value of `v` in `vrs` (`v` being the version byte, and `r`/`s` being the DER values). Since `v` is not encoded by DER signatures, the check for `27 <= v <= 34` was failing because not knowing the `v` value would sometimes require `v` be equal to `None`, `0` or `1`.